# How can I prevent '500 internal server error' because of a long install process?

Tags: plugin-development, 500-internal-error

In one of my plugins, I need to insert about 1000 terms into a custom taxonomy while installing a plugin. I see it's sometimes causing `500 internal server error`. How can I split that work or prevent it from giving an error?

Comment: Can you turn on error reporting/logging and let us know what the error is? A 500 message simply indicates an error occurred, it isn't an error in of itself

Comment: `mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 31 seconds, referer: /wp-admin/network/plugins.php`
`Premature end of script headers: plugins.php, referer: /wp-admin/network/plugins.php`

Comment: Its not server load issue because server is mine

Comment: Nobody suggested it was, you simply ran out of time executing the PHP script. The obvious answer being to separate the 1000 term list into batches to be executed sequentially in separate page requests

Comment: Yeah, i am asking how to do it in question. I know problem as i described in title.

Answer (score 1):

Are your database tables using the InnoDB engine? If so, and the plugin is just for your website, start a transaction, run the inserts, commit the transaction (or rollback on error).

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query('start transaction');
// do the inserts
$wpdb->query('commit');
```

Comment: I can make php executing unlimited but just curious on how i can split work for future development

Comment: OK, so you're not asking for a solution, you want a strategy. There are many, some posted in this stack. Have you tried [searching](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=batch+insert)?